# If column A match, replace all other column of row

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here I have a sheet

```
__A_B_C_D_E_F_G_H_I_J_
1_A___________________
2_B___________________
3_C___________________
4_D___________________
5_E___________________
6_c_1_________4_______
7_b_____2_________5___
8_a___6___5___________
9_e_______________1___
10d_____4_____2_______
```

Now I want to replace colum `B-I` of row `1-5` with value of row `6-10` below, but must match value of column A when upcase.

Ex: A1 = A -> match with A8, so all other column of row 1 will be replace with row 8.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working from your base data:

[image: Original Worksheet]

**INDEX**( **MATCH** ) and **VLOOKUP** will both match lower and uppercase characters as identical, so that association occurs automatically. To preserve the blank cells, they must be caught with an **ISBLANK** command.

The following is the code from cell **B1** in this example:

```
=IF(
  ISBLANK(
    INDEX($A$6:$I$10,
      MATCH($A1,$A$6:$A$10,0),COLUMN()
    )
  ),"",
  INDEX($A$6:$I$10,
    MATCH($A1,$A$6:$A$10,0),COLUMN()
  )
)
```

Using the same locked references as this case, you can drag the formula down and across to fill the range **B1:I5**.

The result will look like this:

[image: Finished Worksheet]

Note that if there is not a corresponding "fill" row for a letter (e.g. an "F" row up top but no matching "f" row below), an **#N/A** error will be thrown.